# How to stop AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have a activity A, it register AlarmManager to trigger another BroadcastReceiver B. When time is reached, onReceive() of B will be called, and start another activity C. A may be closed when C is started.

My problem is: 
- C don't know the pendingIntent in A, how can I call alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent) in C?
- Or, how can I pass pendingIntent from A to B to C?

Pls help.

Answer (score 2):

In my application I created a static method that returned the `PendingIntent` required for the `AlarmManager`, and then I can call it from any class. If you have a `PendingIntent` that doesn't change between times it is called this can work for you. For example, I have:

```
public static PendingIntent getSyncPendingIntent(Context context)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, <classname>.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        return pi;  
    }
```

And I can just call that from any class to get the same `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Thx! It's work:) finially, I declare both alarmManager and pendingIntent as static, and create a static cancel() function in A.

Comment: Glad to hear that worked out: took me a little while to come up with that when I ran into the same situation.

Comment: Problem happen: Start AlarmManager in A -> Kill A by Task Killer -> BroadcastReceiver B triggered -> C -> Call static A.cancel(). the static alarmManager and pindingIntent no more exist! Stopped unexpectedly, and cannot kill the intent.

Comment: The alarm manager can not be static. You want to get the alarm manager everytime using `getSystemService`, but use the static PendingIntent method to get a new, identical PendingIntent every time.

Comment: Thanks Femi! I've been debugging my crashing widget for days. I was using a static alarm manager :P

Comment: @Femi I have a similar use case here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61161676/android-cancel-alarm-and-pendingintent-in-different-activity  Would your answer above help in my case?  If yes, then create "Context context;" then that context is used in the Intent and PendingIntent?

Comment: p.s. I see your original answer was from a long time ago.  With your answer above, Android Studio currently throws an error, stating the non-static i and pi cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: @AJW I can't see how that's possible, if you're using the exact code above. i and pi are local to the function: no one else is referencing them outside this function. Did you try and declare them globally?

Answer (score 0):

It would be far easier to manage the Alarm and its intent in a singleton service than to try to pass it from activity to activity, and far less brittle (you could introduce Activity D somewhere in the middle without having to daisy chain the intent further).

Answer (score 0):

You can register a broadcast receiver in A to listen for a custom action that is broadcasted when C is started

In Activity A

```
private BroadcastReceiver onActivityCStartedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //cancel the pendingIntent for the alarm here
    }
};
```

register the receiver

```
registerReceiver(onActivityCStartedReceiver , new IntentFilter(ACTIVITY_C_STARTED_ACTION));
```

In Activity C call

```
Intent i = new Intent(ACTIVITY_C_STARTED_ACTION);
context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

try it! make use of the messaging system for your good :D

Comment: Is it need to keep A running, to keep alarmManager and pendingIntent un-changed? or declared as static?

Answer (score 0):

To cancel/destroy all the services which you have generated, then generally you need the same "pendingInetent" and "AlarmManager" variable which you have used for starting those services,
 for example if your previous variable is am_mngr and pndngInt then use it like this in your stopservice method.

```
 am_mngr.cancel(pndngInt); // this will cancel the previous servicse...
```